# Use MegaCLI to add a new hard disk to existing RAID0 in Linux

Tags: hard-disk, raid0

There are two hard disks on my machine, but after installing the operating system, it uses only one hard disk to build RAID0.

After installing MegaCLI, I used:

```
MegaCli64 -pdlist -aALL
```

to display the RAID configuration. I found one disk's "Firmware state" is online, but the other's is unconfigured.

Does that mean I need to add the unconfigured disk to the RAID array? How do I add it?

Before yesterday, I had no idea about RAID. Can someone advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved now.And Edouard Fazenda's method is right,but there is one step before adding a new virtual drive.In my case,when I used the command:

> storcli64 show all      or
>    MegaCli64 -CfgForeign -Scan -a0

I found that the other hard disk's DG(DriveGroup) is foreign.I think that why I cann't use that hard disk to add a new virtual drive.So the first work is clearing it by the following commond:

> MegaCli64 -CfgForeign -Clear -a0

After that,we can use the hard disk to add a new virtual drive by the following commond:

> MegaCli64 -CfgLdAdd r0[EnclosureID:SlotID] -a0     or
>   storcli64 /c0 add vd type=r0 drives=EnclosureID:SlotID

Now we can find sd[a|b|c...] directories in /etc,and we can use the hard disk normally.

There is also some informations about this problem:
[https://serverfault.com/questions/331807/megacli-is-killing-me-any-help-appreciated]

In the end,I want to say thank you to @Warren Young and @Edouard Fazenda for giving so many clues to me.

Answer (score 2):

So first of all to see the disks behind a LSI RAID controller you can use storcli tool or megacli.

I would suggest to use storcli that is more user friendly and which you can download from he LSI website. This is the tool that I describe below.

URL to download storcli : [Storcli Tool](http://docs.avagotech.com/docs/1.20.15_StorCLI)

Intro:

```
/cx        Controller specific commands
/ex        Enclosure specific commands
/sx        Slot/PD specific commands
/vx        Virtual drive specific commands
/dx        Disk group specific commands
```

To see controller information :

```
sudo storcli /cX show all
```

To see the disk information

```
sudo storcli /cX/eX/sX show all
```

To create a RAID 1 :

```
sudo storcli /cx add vd type=r1 drives=[EnclosureID:SlotID]
```

URL to the reference manual of Storcli Tool : [Manual in PDF format](http://docs.avagotech.com/docs/12352476)

Comment: Actually,I just want to use the other hard disk as an independent disk.The only purpose of using the disk is storing data,but considering the security of the data on the disk.So how could I achieve that?Could you tell me how to do with megacli?

Comment: @seabiscuitxf: You may be able to use `megacli` or `storcli` to create single-disk RAIDs, as I mentioned in my other answer, but if your controller is compatible with the IT mode hack, I'd do it that way instead. That seems is more in line with your actual goal, which is to treat this RAID controller as a raw-disk SCSI controller. You don't use either of these tools to re-flash your firmware.